# Installing scikit-learn on ubuntu

Tags: python, machine-learning, ubuntu-14.04

I am having problems installing scikit-learn on ubuntu. Can someone help me. I am triyng the following:

```
>>> sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-numpy python-setuptools python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3-base
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-numpy python-setuptools python-scipy libatlas-dev libatlas3-base
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: exit() or ctrl+d to get out of the python interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running this from a Python Interpreter. Enter `exit()` and then paste the command again